Building Smooth Page Transitions and Preloader for a Portfolio Site: Seeking Guidance on Advanced Techniques with NextJS and GSAP
I'm building a portfolio site using NextJS app router + gsap, implement simple page transition, and I don't know how to

build a nicely preloader component, at this time I'm using a component with delay of 3s in template.tsx
complex page transition, e.g each page transition (from index to contact, from index to about), I want transition like container in Barba.js
It would be great if you guys give me an article or github repo about this
Thanks

I’ve tried implementing a basic preloader component with a simple 3-second delay using setTimeout in template.tsx. The preloader works, but it feels static and doesn't provide the smooth, engaging experience I was hoping for.
For the page transitions, I tried using simple CSS transitions, but they’re not as dynamic as I want. I’m looking for something more fluid and immersive, similar to the container transitions provided by Barba.js, where each page transition (e.g., from the index page to contact or about) feels like a seamless shift rather than a hard switch.
I was expecting to achieve smoother, more complex transitions that enhance the overall user experience, but I haven’t found a clear solution yet. I’m seeking advice on how to build these features, or examples to guide me in the right direction.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I implemented page transition base on this tutorial [https://medium.com/@josiah.webdev/page-transitions-with-gsap-next-js-app-router-5508cee43a80](NextJS page transition)
anh this is transition I want to implement, just like https://barba.js.org/
